# the difference between “across the street from” and "down the street from"

Tags: meaning

> across the street from the library

> down the street from the library

Are there any differences between them?

Comment: What happens when you translate those phrases into your own language on [Google Translate](translate.google.com)? Do you not get clearly different translations?

Comment: @gotube No, no. I just find it difficult to understand it. The difference between "across" and "down" isn't very clear when translated in my own language. So I want to understand it in the way of thinking in English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are different.

*Across the street from the library* has a specific meaning: they are at the same position on the same street, one on the left and one on the right. That is: if I drive on this street, there is some position where I can look left to see the library, and look right to see the other building.

*Down the street from the library* has an equally specific but different meaning: they are on the same street but different positions. So if I am on the street and see the library on one side, I have to keep driving further (along the same street) to find the other building.

Comment: So, "the library" here is a landmark, which is in order to give the direction of the other building. Am I right?

Comment: Many native speakers get this wrong. I've heard, many times, people say: "something is across the road", and then discover it's 500 metres away.